# return substring match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to get just a part of a string with a regex

this is the string i am testing

`class1 container _box _box_CEC493`

the string is a series of classes applied to an element.

what i would like to get is just `CEC493` which changes since the regex will be applied to a bunch of different elements (therefore string like the one above)

the regex i am using now is

`/\s_box_([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/`

which returns

`_box_CEC493, CEC493`

How can i modify it in order to get just the second value (`CEC493`)?

Thank you

Comment: Is it always going to be `CEC493` or is this value dynamic? Will it sometimes be `CEC523`?

Comment: `_box_CEC493, CEC493` looks like a match *array* viewed as a string, in which case `CEC493` is in `matchVar[1]`

Comment: @Banning yes it is a dynamic value.

Comment: @AlexK. Thatis my actual solution but i would like it get directly from the regex because there may be the case that those classes are not there so to write matchVar[1] will hold a null an therefore an error in my script. Thank you guys for your inputs

Comment: Can't you just detect that; `if (matchVar != null) ..` if not you will need to explain what you have control over

Comment: @Donnie So what is the constant then? `CEC`? and then is it always `3` numbers after `CEC`?

Comment: Why not use string manipulation to find the last instance of `_box_`? You don't need a regex for this.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably just split the string:

```
var str = "class1 container _box _box_CEC493";
var match = str.split('_').pop();
alert(match);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gHjxc/)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way regexes come back is like this:

[0]: Whole result

[1]: First parentheses capture group

etc

So the standard way that people access these is with `result[1]`. Does that cause any issues in your case?

Comment: That's how i managed to do it right now.
But there may be the case where the regex doesn't match anything so result[1] will be null.
I thought there is actually a way to reach my desired result directly through the regex. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Why not check if `typeof result[1] == 'undefined'`?

Comment: Unless your capture group is marked as optional, then either the array will exist with two values, or the test function will return null entirely. Since you use a + rather than *, then in order to match there must be something in that group.

Answer (score 0):

**[updated]**

instead of selecting all characters, select until an unwanted character,, and since you are selecting from a number of classes, it is possible that you have the `_box_..` class alone without a space before it, so don't use space at the beginning of your regex selector.

```
str.match(/_box_([^\s]*)/)[1]
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/SYcCm/2/)**